# Array usage inside the query statement - MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hey guys I'm new to PHP yet I gave a shot. There is a change in the requirements now for what I do. The values B1 to B11 are not the same any more. It can be from B1 to B6 or B1 to B50. So I can tell that I need an array to pass the value. However what I need to know is how do I include them in the $sql statement. Instead of B1 to B11 do I have to use any variables?
  Below is the code for reference.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php

    $DB_hostname = "localhost";
    $DB_Name = "root";
    $DB_pass = "pass123";


    if(isset($_GET["slot"])){
       $tableName = $_GET["slot"];
       $db = $_GET["db"];
    }
     echo $tableName;

   $con = mysql_connect($DB_Hostname,$DB_Name,$DB_pass) or die(mysql_error());

   // Create table
   mysql_select_db($tableName = $_GET["slot"];, $con);
   if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE $tableName"))==1) {
      echo "Table exists";
   }else {

       echo "Table does not exist";
    // Create table
    mysql_select_db($db, $con);
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName
    (
    Slot int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Slot),
    B1 TEXT NOT NULL,
    B2 TEXT NOT NULL,
    B3 TEXT NOT NULL,
    B4 TEXT NOT NULL,
    B5 TEXT NOT NULL,
    B6 TEXT NOT NULL,
    B7 TEXT NOT NULL,
    B8 TEXT NOT NULL,
    B9 TEXT NOT NULL,
    B10 TEXT NOT NULL,
    B11 TEXT NOT NULL
   )";
   mysql_query($sql,$con);

   }


   mysql_close($con);
   ?>
```

Comment: You got any error..??

Comment: No error on this. The condition is that Im receiving the column B1 to B11 ( in this case is 11 ) as an array.It can be 4 or anything. It must be read like how I do for "$tableName = $_GET["slot"];" the  Its not fixed.

Comment: May my ans will help you...

Comment: /*... It can be 4 or anything..*/  column name can not be repeated.It Should be unique.

Comment: Yes its incremental. So I can run a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure why you need to have so many columns inside your table. A better solution might to have $tableName only have two columns, one for the slot, and the other that defines how many slots the table will have.

The `slot` column will then be set as `auto_increment` inside MySQL, which means each time a row is added to the database, the number increments.

The next table, will include all of the data that was originally in the other columns. It would have three columns, the `slot` column, the `position` column (which would replace the B$x columns from the original table) and the `value` column, where the TEXT data is placed.

This makes your database relational (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model)

You can then do a LEFT JOIN on the two tables to retrieve all of the data (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

---

That being said, for your current solution, you would simply need to change some of your code.

```
if(isset($_GET["slot"])){
   $tableName = $_GET["slot"];
   $db = $_GET["db"];
}
   
//getting the slot count
if (isset($_GET['slots'])) {
   $slots = (int)$_GET['slots'];
}

if (!isset($slots) or !isset($tableName)) {
   echo "Please first provide the right data to this script!";
   exit;
}

// Create the table
$_columns = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $slots; $i++) {
    $_columns[] = "B$i TEXT NOT NULL ";
}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName
(
Slot int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Slot),
" . implode( ', ', $_columns) . "
)";
```

Comment: if (isset($_GET['slots'])) {
   $slots = (int)$_GET['slot'];
} What does this line do here?

Comment: It gets the slots from the URL (ie, how many 'B' columns you want)

So, if you wanted B1=>B10, you would use the URL ?slot=mynewtable&slots=10

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your B1,B2 values in an array and then create your `$sql` variable like this. This will work for any number of entries.

```
<?php
$values=array();
$values[]="B1";
$values[]="B2";
$values[]="B3";
$values[]="B4";

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName
    (
    Slot int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Slot)";

    foreach($values as $value)
    {
    $sql.=",
    $value TEXT NOT NULL";
    }
    $sql.=")";


echo $sql;

?>
```

You can also simplify it further. If those values are always going to start with B and end on a numeric value then you could just simply run a `$count` variable and loop as many times and add that rather than having to hand type all the B values in an array.

Comment: but I don't have a fixed value. So I should be passing my array throught the http://IP/file.php?db=dbname&colArray=?" what do I pass here ?

Comment: You can create the array on top of your existing code, and yes you can `POST` the array values too

Comment: @Gautam whats the difference between this answer and your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

You can pass the array as like IP/file.php?db=dbname&my_arr=B1,B2,B3

```
$my_cols = explode(',', $_GET['my_arr']);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName     (
Slot int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Slot)";
foreach($my_cols as $col){
    $sql .= " ,`".$col."` TEXT NOT NULL";
}
$sql .= ')';
```

Comment: I'm trying Gautam. Sorry give me a while

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "12345678") or die(mysql_error());
$tableName="new_table";
// Create table
mysql_select_db("spend_track", $con);
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE $tableName")) == 1) {
  echo "Table exists";
} else {

  // Create table
  mysql_select_db($db, $con);
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName
    (
    Slot int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Slot),
    $filed1 TEXT NOT NULL,
    $filed2 TEXT NOT NULL,
    $filed3 TEXT NOT NULL,
    $filed4 TEXT NOT NULL,
    $filed5 TEXT NOT NULL,
    $filed6 TEXT NOT NULL,
    $filed7 TEXT NOT NULL,
    $filed8 TEXT NOT NULL,
    $filed9 TEXT NOT NULL,
    $filed10 TEXT NOT NULL,
    $filed11 TEXT NOT NULL
   )";
 if(mysql_query($sql, $con)){
   echo "success to create";
 }else{
   echo "failed to create";
 }
}


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Here using variable for instead of direct value. Please note that filed name should be unique.It can not be repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the user information in connection string. It should be like

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that the question is absolutely not clear. What do you want to do? Insert new records? Create the table? And wait, why should we know that some requirements have changed, we don't know original requirements ;)

There still two things to notice here.

1. Escape your variables with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function.
2. Better use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) because MySQL extension you are using is deprecated.